# AWS DMS not able to connect Mysql source DB but DB is connecting from mysql command

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms, amazon-aurora

I am working on a project, where I want to replicate data from a source Aurora Mysql to Kinesis with AWS data migration service (DMS).

I am able to connect to source Mysql DB from mysql command and can see whole database:

```
mysql --host=<host>.amazonaws.com --port=8200 --user=<user> -p
```

But when I am starting replication task of DMS, DMS is giving connection issue with source DB. Connection with destination (Kinesis) is fine.

Testing connection for source DB from DMS, giving error:

**Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Cannot connect to ODBC provider  ODBC general error., Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: HY000 NativeError: 2003 Message: [unixODBC][MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver]Can't connect to MySQL server on '.compute-1.amazonaws.com' (110)**

I tried from AWS docs but I am not able to figure out the issue. In the network ACL of VPC, I have allowed ALL incoming traffic for its VPC.

Comment: How are your security groups (on mysql) set up?

Comment: I have no access to set it or see it currently. Does it require a change? I can access DB from mysql command and even can use mysqldump command.

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue, not sure if you have figured out the solution. Network setup was fine, was using the same VPC for both RDS and DMS Replication instance, there was no issue with security group, however the **issue** was with the **version of DMS**.
RDS MySQL version is 5.7, the ODBC driver present in the higher version doesn't seem to work with the RDS instance or probably something is limiting connection to RDS MySQL 5.7 in DMS, **launched** a new replication instance in DMS with **version 3.3.3** and the DB connectivity worked fine, also data movement is happening fine